# How to Create Collection Like QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, list, model, django-queryset

#The below statement is valid
`medical = Medical.objects.filter(ref_no=ref_no)`
`print(medical)`

#This is the output which contains two records
<QuerySet [<Medical: Medical object (1)>, <Medical: Medical object (2)>]>

#This is the model for Medical

```
class Medical(models.Model):
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    med_ref = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

#The value return from database are encrypted. I have a class that successfully decrypt the value.

```
med = Setup.TransformData(medical)

def TransformData(medicals):
    medList = []
    if medicals.exists():
        for med in medicals:
            medical = Medical()
            medical.radius = EncryptionDecryption.DataDecryption(med.ref_no)
            medical.radius = EncryptionDecryption.DataDecryption(med.med_ref)
            medical.radius = EncryptionDecryption.DataDecryption(med.status)
            medList.append(medical)
        return medList
```

My challenge is that in this class, I am not able to re-create the medical
collection to return the value like QuerySet or some other format so that i can loop through it
to get the decrypted values for each records.

Please can someone help me re-write the TransformData method to return an iterable values. Thanks

Comment: You should work with a custom model field that transparently encrypts/decryptes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: or another option is to override `from_db`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.from_db

Comment: Ok, let me see if understand what the link suggested. Thanks

Comment: I could not follow through probably because am new to django. can you help with a code snippet? Please

Comment: @Anderson can you give more information about how the data is encrypted/decrypted? There are packages like [django-encrypted-model-fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/) which can be used to do this

Comment: My issue is not with the encryption/decryption. It is how to create custom model field that will store and return records  that I can loop through. This is what an trying to achieve with the TransformData method I wrote.

Comment: If i have 3 records, for example:

John  Male  20
Kate  Female  25
Sandra Female 45

How will i create a collection of this that I can loop through with 
like this for rec in records
         print(rec.name) 
                print(rec.gender) 
                print(rec.age)